# How to report the corellation of one column in relation to other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a data as:

```
df1 df2 df3 df4 df5
1    3  3   4    5
4    4  3   4    3
5    5  1   -2   1
9    7  3   0    -2
```

I would like to report the strong relationship in terms of corelation between column df1 and the other columns(df2,df3,df4 and df5)

The output should look like this:

```
df1 is strongly corelated to df2
 df1 is not strongly corelated to df3
 df1 is not strongly corelated to df4
 df1 is strongly corelated to df5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Onde ide a is use [`DataFrame.corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) and strong correlation is defined here like absolute value is  greater like `0.7`:

```
m = df.corrwith(df.pop('df1')).abs().gt(0.7)
print (m)
df2     True
df3    False
df4    False
df5     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
for k, v in m.items():
    if v:
       print (f'df1 is strongly corelated to {k}')
    else:
       print (f'df1 is not strongly corelated to {k}')
       
df1 is strongly corelated to df2
df1 is not strongly corelated to df3
df1 is not strongly corelated to df4
df1 is strongly corelated to df5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.corr()` to compute pairwise correlation of columns